# Modifying buffer focus control (pop-to-buffer vs display-buffer)

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a straightforward way (via defadvice or otherwise) to change the focus behavior of buffers such as help, grep, occur?  In particular, I would like to modify the behavior of `M-x occur` to take me to the *Occur* buffer directly.  Some modes (e.g. ESS) provide finer-grained control over the display of such "temporary" buffers, but is there a general strategy for buffers where such controls aren't provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'occur-hook (lambda () (pop-to-buffer occur-buf)))

(add-hook 'help-mode-hook (lambda () (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer "*Help*"))))

(add-hook 'grep-mode-hook (lambda () (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer "*grep*"))))
```

A general approach, as an alternative, is to use `special-display-regexps` or `special-display-buffer-names` to make such buffers `special-display`, which puts them in a separate frame (and selects it).  E.g.:

```
(setq special-display-regexps '("[ ]?[*][^*]+[*]"))
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the `special-display` handler function to customize the focus behavior based on the buffer name?  E.g. if the buffer name is "\*Occur*" it would use `pop-to-buffer` instead of the default of putting it in a separate frame?  That would make for a truly generic solution.

Comment: 1. Emacs 24 radically changes how things are done, and you can pretty much do anything you like, IIUC -- see the doc. 2. For older versions, "special-display" is pretty much geared toward a frame (you can specify frame properties etc. on a per buffer basis). But you can alternatively force a buffer to *not* use a separate window or frame. See the Emacs manual, nodes `Special Buffer Frames` and `Force Same Window`. A special-display handler function can of course do anything you want, but trying to get it not to use a separate frame would be contorted and clumsy.